# SharePoint 2013 Register Workflow Error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

When I try to run the PowerShell Command to Register my workflow service on my SharePoint 2013 server I get the errors below in my ULS and in the PowerShell Window.

```
Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://sharepoint.domain" -WorkflowHostUri "https://workflow.domain:12290" -ScopeName "DevSP" -AllowOAuthHttp  -Force
```

```
Register-SPWorkflowService : Object reference not set to an instance of an
object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://slcdevsp144" -WorkflowHost ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...WorkflowService:
   RegisterSPWorkflowService) [Register-SPWorkflowService], NullReferenceExce
  ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell
   .RegisterSPWorkflowService
```

```
06/11/2019 10:24:50.80  PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      Updating SPPersistedObject WorkflowDeploymentGroupTypePersistedObject Name=WorkflowDeploymentGroupTypePersistedObject. Version: 9146151 Ensure: False, HashCode: 64984250, Id: f0f5a80e-9feb-4aaf-9e86-abcf973d7881, Stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.RegisterWorkflowLifecycleManagementEnvironment()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProcessRecord()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)     at System.Management.Automation.Pipeli... c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.80* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ...neOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)     at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderb...  c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.80* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ...ar, Object inputToProcess)     at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.Complete()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc()     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     ...  c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.80* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ...at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()      c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.80  PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      Updating SPPersistedObject WorkflowAppPartTypePersistedObject Name=WorkflowAppPartTypePersistedObject. Version: 9146153 Ensure: False, HashCode: 38610103, Id: 4527f25c-501e-41e6-9ddf-67ff26bb9100, Stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.RegisterWorkflowLifecycleManagementEnvironment()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProcessRecord()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)     at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipe... c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.80* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ...line(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)     at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object input...  c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.80* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ...ToProcess)     at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.Complete()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc()     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Thread...  c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.80* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ...ing.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()      c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.85  PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      Updating SPPersistedObject WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy Name=Workflow Service Application Proxy. Version: 9146293 Ensure: False, HashCode: 49841781, Id: 5bf2865b-f8bd-4266-a372-0aa6da484e54, Stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.Update()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.IWorkflowService.SetProperty[T](SPSite site, WorkflowServiceProperty property, T value)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServerPairingContext.RegisterFarm()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProcessRecord()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor... c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.85* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ....ProcessRecord()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)     at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpret...  c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.85* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ...er.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)     at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)     at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.Complete()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc(...  c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.85* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ...)     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc()     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()     c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.85  PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      Updating SPPersistedObject WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy Name=Workflow Service Application Proxy. Version: 9146301 Ensure: False, HashCode: 49841781, Id: 5bf2865b-f8bd-4266-a372-0aa6da484e54, Stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.Update()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.IWorkflowService.SetProperty[T](SPSite site, WorkflowServiceProperty property, T value)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.SetWorkflowServiceAddress(SPSite site, String uri)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServerPairingContext.RegisterFarm()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProc... c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.85* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ...essRecord()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)     at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management....  c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.85* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ...Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)     at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)     at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.Complete()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)     at System.Management...  c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.85* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ....Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc()     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()     c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.86  PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      Updating SPPersistedObject WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy Name=Workflow Service Application Proxy. Version: 9146303 Ensure: False, HashCode: 49841781, Id: 5bf2865b-f8bd-4266-a372-0aa6da484e54, Stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.Update()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.IWorkflowService.SetProperty[T](SPSite site, WorkflowServiceProperty property, T value)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServerPairingContext.RegisterFarm()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProcessRecord()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor... c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.86* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ....ProcessRecord()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)     at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpret...  c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.86* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ...er.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)     at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)     at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.Complete()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc(...  c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.86* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ...)     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc()     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()     c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.88  PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      Updating SPPersistedObject WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy Name=Workflow Service Application Proxy. Version: 9146305 Ensure: False, HashCode: 49841781, Id: 5bf2865b-f8bd-4266-a372-0aa6da484e54, Stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.Update()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.IWorkflowService.SetProperty[T](SPSite site, WorkflowServiceProperty property, T value)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServerPairingContext.RegisterFarm()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProcessRecord()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor... c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.88* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ....ProcessRecord()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)     at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpret...  c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.88* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ...er.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)     at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)     at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.Complete()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc(...  c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.88* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ...)     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc()     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()     c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.88  PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      Updating SPPersistedObject WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy Name=Workflow Service Application Proxy. Version: 9146307 Ensure: False, HashCode: 49841781, Id: 5bf2865b-f8bd-4266-a372-0aa6da484e54, Stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.Update()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServerPairingContext.RegisterFarm()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProcessRecord()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)     at Syste... c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.88* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ...m.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)     at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action...  c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.88* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ...`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)     at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.Complete()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc()     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state,...  c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.88* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqz    Medium      ... Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()    c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.89  PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Application Authentication      afron   High        Attempting to download security token service json metadata from 'https://workflow.domain:12290/$System/$Metadata/json/1'.  c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.91  PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           Application Authentication      afroq   High        Security token service json metadata successfully downloaded from 'https://workflow.domain:12290/$System/$Metadata/json/1'. c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.91  PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           PowerShell                      6tf2    High        System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPTrustedProviderBase.UpdateFromMetadataFeed(Boolean isFirstTime)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPTrustedProviderBase..ctor(SPPersistedObject parent, String name, String description, X509Certificate2 certificate, Uri metadataEndPoint, SPSecurityTokenServiceJsonMetadataDocument metadataDocument)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPTrustedProviderBase..ctor(SPPersistedObject parent, String name, String description, Uri metadataEndPoint)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceHelper.EnsureTrustedSecurityTokenService(Uri metadataEndpoint, Boolean allowHttp)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.Wor... c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.91* PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           PowerShell                      6tf2    High        ...kflowServerPairingContext.ConfigureOAuth(Boolean allowOAuthHttp)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProcessRecord()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord()   c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
06/11/2019 10:24:50.91  PowerShell.exe (0x2A04)                     0x2C98  SharePoint Foundation           PowerShell                      91ux    High        Error Category: InvalidData    Target Object  Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService  Details  NULL  RecommendedAction NULL c2ab5670-d75f-4010-81c4-3c27301574b8
```

Comment: To be clear I had to condense my ULS log to fit within the allowed limit. 
Also for security concerns I changed the actual server and login names to generic ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out after a lot of research. The problem was the self signed cert that the workflow manager had created has expired. I had to run the following Powershell script on my workflow server first

```
Set-WFCertificate -SslCertificateThumbprint <thumbprint> -EncryptionCertificateThumbprint <thumbprint>

Set-WFNextOutboundCertificateReference -ServiceURI https://server.domain:12290/ -Thumbprint <thumbprint>

Stop-WFHost

Update-WFHost

Start-WFHost

Set-WFNextOutboundCertificateAsCurrent -ServiceURI https://server.domain:12290/
```

Then I had to export the certificate from Internet Explorer as a Base 64 Encoded X.509 (.cer)

Then on my SharePoint farm I had to install the cert I just exported to the trust store using the following Powershell

```
$cert = Get-PfxCertificate "FULLY QUALIFIED PATH TO Cert"
New-SPTrustedRootAuthority -Name "Dev Workflow Farm Cert" -Certificate $cert
```

Finally after all of that inside the SharePoint 2013 Central Administration go to Monitoring Then Review Job Definitions and then find `Refresh Trusted Security Token Services Metadata feed.`
Click on it and then click Run Now

Wait 5 mins and then run your
`Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://sharepoint.domain" -WorkflowHostUri "https://workflow.domain:12290" -ScopeName "DevSP" -AllowOAuthHttp  -Force`